# vim: How do I line up ruby options?

Tags: ruby, vim

With vim how do I to turn this:

```
t.string :crypted_password :null => false
t.string :password_salt, :null => false
```

into this:

```
t.string :crypted_password,  :null => false
t.string :password_salt,     :null => false
```

without manually adding the spaces to each line?

Comment: Honestly?  Just add spaces manually.  The width of tabs can change, though they are 2 spaces wide by Ruby convention.

Comment: :P I thought someone might have a little script or technique to do this quickly is all. It's not like this is holding me up or anything. I swear I've seen it done before. I prefer spaces - good point. Updating question...

Comment: This question *does not* belong on superuser. In general, questions about vim belong here (as it is largely a programmer's editor): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-so-or-su And in this particular case, we can clearly see that it's a common programming text operation - everyone likes to line stuff up. Case in point: the plugin in my answer is designed for code alignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be possible with the [Align plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294). Conveniently enough, you actually only need to align on whitespace to accomplish this, and Align has a built-in shortcut for that: `\tsp` (it operates on the visual mode selection).

If actual use cases could get more complex and whitespace alignment doesn't give the result you want, you can also define your own alignment - Align lets you specify it pretty precisely, with multiple separators, skipping separators...

Another alignment plugin: [Tabular](http://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) ([documentation here](http://github.com/godlygeek/tabular/blob/master/doc/Tabular.txt)).  I personally haven't used it but Greg recommends it in the comments - it delimits by regular expression instead of fixed string.

Comment: Nice! This is the sort of thing I was looking for. I'm gonna check it out. If it works for my case I'll mark as accepted. For now +1.

Comment: I use the align plugin all the time to align text into columns or align assignments on "=". You might want to look at the Tabular plugin also, which lets you define a regex pattern for alignment. There are times the align plugin won't get there so I use tabular.

Comment: @Greg: I hadn't heard of Tabular and seem to find it on vim scripts - do you have a link?

Comment: check http://github.com/godlygeek/tabular or its docs at http://github.com/godlygeek/tabular/blob/master/doc/Tabular.txt